# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in CommentsController#destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am getting this error while i am going to delete a comment associated with a post.

// my CommentsController

```
def destroy

        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])

        @comments = @post.comments.find(params[:comment])
        @comments.destroy
        redirect_to post_path(@post)

    end
```

// my form::

```
 <p>
    <strong><%= comment.commenter %>:  </strong>


     <%= comment.body %>
    <strong> at </strong><%= comment.created_at %>

    <%= link_to 'Delete Comments', [comment.post,comment], method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you Sure'} %>
  </p>
```

I am getting the error in ::

**@comments = @post.comments.find(params[:comment])**

please tell me where i am wrong..

Comment: Please paste whole error message.

Comment: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in CommentsController#destroy
Couldn't find Comment without an ID

Comment: @MarekLipka :: above is the whole message..

Comment: Please paste relevant log entry with parameters passed into `destroy` action. Or, please try my answer, since it probably solves your issue.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting `id` in `params[:comment]` ?

Comment: yes @RSB i am quiet sure.. because i am creating the comment through this command only..

Comment: @user3322822 logs please.

Comment: Please paste your routes for destroy action here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably should have:

```
@comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
@comment.destroy
```

Since by default, nested resource record id is referenced by `params[:id]` in `destroy` action.

Comment: :: i changed that but still not working.. same error is showing

Comment: i am creating the comment with "@post = Post.find (params[:post_id])"
and this is working fine..

Comment: @user3322822 like I said, please paste relevant logs fragment. It would also be good to know how you implement link to destroy action in appropriate view.

Comment: :: 
Request

Parameters:

{"_method"=>"delete",
 "authenticity_token"=>"sdrKECi78B2oDMjnAU2EqLekrrdWJ+QeSm21iMgpbQw=",
 "post_id"=>"9",
 "id"=>"18"}

above is my request parameters..so it is actually taking appropriate parameter.

Comment: @user3322822 it's clear that my solution should work unless you're trying to destroy non-existing already comment.
And BTW, instead of pasting it in comment, you should always update question itself.

Comment: :: This is an existing comment.. because i can see it in the view and then i am trying to delete it.. so i am sure that it is in the db.

Comment: @user3322822 do you see it also after page refresh?

Comment: @RSB :: flash[:success] = "Comment deleted" 

this command is not working.. i mean its not displaying any messages

Comment: @Marek Lipka :: your solution is also working after restarting the server.. i dont what is happening..

Comment: @user3322822 I thought so. I think maybe you needed to refresh your `post` page to show really existing comments.

Comment: Check the edited answer, to display it on the page you have to include `<%= flash[:success] %>` in view file. You are free to accept any answer. I'm just saying that try using `where` instead of `find` to avoid errors. No hard feelings @MarekLipka. I'm still a beginner and would love to learn from seniors. :)

Comment: @RSB error hiding is an [anti-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_hiding). So I guess you should remove your downvote from my answer.

Comment: Sorry @MarekLipka.. it might be a mistake.. i have not done it intentionally..actually i was going through this question thread a few days back..The answer is correct..

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

```
@post = Post.where(:id => params[:post_id]).first
unless @post.blank?
  @comment = @post.comments.where(:id => params[:id]).first
  unless @comment.blank?
    @comment.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Comment deleted" 
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  else
    flash[:notice] = "Comment not found"
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end
end
```

The difference between `find` and `where` is that, `where` returns an empty array if no comment is found. But find raise an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error. Is it clear? If no comment of that `id` is present in the table then it will return an empty array, and in second line I have added a condition that if comment is not found don't perform `destroy` action. I've simply handled the error.

You have to include `<%= flash[:notice] %>` in view file to see the error/success message

Comment: Don't you think the action should raise an error if no record is found instead of pretending that everything is ok and it destroyed `comment` record? 
Also, it's not really a solution, it's only a hack to hide an error.

Comment: Of course we can define a flash to display error or success message, don't downvote without giving it a thought :)

Comment: @RSB :: yes it is working fine .. but can you tell me the logic behind the first line please..
Thanks//

Comment: @RSB did you read the second part of my comment? Your answer doesn't solve the main issue, which is unexpected error. If this "solution" is taken, we'll probably see OP on StackOverflow with another question in few minutes.

Comment: thanks for accepting the answer, as @MarekLipka raised a concern, you should define a flash to show error or success message

Comment: @user3322822 I can tell you the logic. It doesn't raise error if the record doesn't exist. So it isn't really any solution, because if there's really a problem with finding your record, this action won't destroy anything.

Comment: @RSB flash message is really least problem with this "solution".

Comment: @Marek Lipka :: can you please tell me your logic behind your concern??
i am really new to rails.. so i am just trying to learn from errors..

Comment: I have edited the answer, please check the difference between `find` and `where`

Comment: Like I said, this "solution" differs from mine that this doesn't raise any error if record you're trying to destroy doesn't exist. Your problem was that you were facing a strange error - like if there weren't any comment with this id (and given post_id, of course), but this comment existed before, when you were clicking on the link to `destroy` action. And this is the main issue, that this answer only hides from you.

Comment: And BTW, @RSB, why exactly did you downvote my answer?

Comment: @MarekLipka I'm here to learn and help, In your answer if no comment of `params[id]` is found then it will throw an error. So better to use `where` instead of `find`. Does this make sense Sir?

Comment: @RSB what's wrong with this approach? Especially since even the scaffolds in rails works this way by default?